# sh can't interpret ./gradlew script on Mac

Tags: bash, gradle, unix, sh, gradlew

I have a Gradle project that I have recently cloned. The project was originally created on a Windows machine.

I am able to run Gradle tasks in IntelliJ just fine, but the `./gradlew` shell script is not working.

First it appeared that the shell script is not executable.

```
$ ./gradlew
zsh: permission denied: ./gradlew
```

So, I gave it execution permissions:

```
$ chmod +x ./gradlew
```

But when I run it again, I get the following errors:

```
$ ./gradlew 
./gradlew: line 203: -Dorg.gradle.appname=gradlew: command not found
./gradlew: line 204: -classpath: command not found
./gradlew: line 205: org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain: command not found
./gradlew: line 206: ^: command not found
Error: Could not find or load main class ^
```

The code in concern is the following:

```
set -- ^
        "-Dorg.gradle.appname=$APP_BASE_NAME" ^
        -classpath "$CLASSPATH" ^
        org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain ^
        "$@"
```

IntelliJ is showing that `./gradlew` is using `LF` line endings.

[image: Line endings]

I also converted the rest of the repo:

```
find . -type f -not -path './.git/*' -print0 | xargs -0 dos2unix
```

My interpreter:

```
$ sh --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (arm64-apple-darwin21)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

My login shell is:

```
$ zsh --version
zsh 5.8.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin21.0)
```

Comment: Those shouldn't be on separate lines, unless the lines end with backslash to continue them to the next line.

Comment: Replace the `^` characters with backslashes.

Comment: @mitchkman did Barmar's suggestion help? That is definitely an issue. It perfectly matches your symptoms.